# How to make java.io.Console display a default for the user to confirm or modify?

Tags: java, console, java-io

the new http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html class seems ok for user input from the console, however, it seems to provide no way to read a line but with the default already filed in (so the user only has to press enter to confirm or delete to modify).

How can i do this with the class?

Answer (score 0):

If the line is empty, use the default.  Using commons-lang's StringUtils (or your favorite way of testing for empty lines)

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(lineRead)) lineRead = "whatever default";
```

Comment: I don't want that. That is easy. What i do want is that the prompt displays the default, and the user can edit it, just like if he had written it.

Comment: BTW, i can't use Robot, since the "default" is actually variable. and translating a arbitrary string to keycodes is impossible.